# Restkit: Map relationship from JSON parentId

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit-0.20

How would I manage to map the following JSON with Restkit? The following JSON contains a ParentId (ParentMenu) and MenuId, in which I would like to use in order to map a core data relationship from my Entity (Product) -->> (SubMenus).

```
Items": [
{
"PriceExclVat": 39.6,
"MenuId": 1100,
"Count": 1,
"ParentMenu": null
},
{
"PriceExclVat": 0,
"MenuId": 1104,
"Count": 1,
"ParentMenu": 1100
},
{
"PriceExclVat": 0,
"MenuId": 1106,
"Count": 1,
"ParentMenu": 1100
},
{
"PriceExclVat": 0,
"MenuId": 1102,
"Count": 1,
"ParentMenu": 1100
}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a connection to your mapping.

```
[mapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"parent" connectedBy:@{ @"ParentMenu" : @"MenuId" }];
```

Replace `@"parent"` with the name of your parent relationship.